# Best Practices: Setting Non-configurable Types in a Substrate Pallet

Tags: pallet

I'm currently working on a custom Substrate pallet and am trying to understand the best practices surrounding the `Config` trait. I've come across a design decision and would appreciate some guidance.

In my pallet, I have the following:

```rust
/// Base URI limit
const BASE_URI_LIMIT_U32: u32 = u8::MAX as u32;
/// Base URI limit type
type BaseURILimit = ConstU32<BASE_URI_LIMIT_U32>;
/// Base URI type
pub type BaseURI = BoundedVec<u8, BaseURILimit>;
```

Given that `BaseURILimit` is supposed to be **non-configurable** and constant across different runtimes using this pallet, is there any reason or advantage to moving it into the pallet's `Config` trait?

I'm trying to adhere to best practices and ensure maintainability. Any insights or recommendations would be invaluable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that it should never change, then that approach is fine.

> Given that BaseURILimit is supposed to be non-configurable and constant across different runtimes using this pallet, is there any reason or advantage to moving it into the pallet's Config trait?

Its fine to have some things non-configurable if there is a good reason to. Personally i would make `BASE_URI_LIMIT_U32` and the other type public as well to make downstream usage a bit easier.

Answer (score -1):

Usually it's not best practice store unlimited size of BoundedVec into runtime, and better to add the upper limit const into runtime rather than pallet.

Comment: I hold some concerns:


1. Inherently, a BoundedVec cannot possess an unlimited capacity.
2. The ability to define a limit at runtime suggests its adaptability. This means pallets with varied limits can be created, which contradicts the non-configurable requirement.

Could you provide some clarity regarding these doubts?

Comment: "unlimited size of BoundedVec" this makes no sense. The code is clearly using `u8::MAX` as limit.

Answer (score -1):

As Ron suggested, we should store it as a constant in runtime like [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ec6be6ed664f09098795a44cbe91c2d465662e9e/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L603C1-L603C1)
and then use it in the pallet config like [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/ec6be6ed664f09098795a44cbe91c2d465662e9e/frame/staking/src/pallet/mod.rs#L261C5-L261C5)